# Trying to figure out why my JSON.parse function doesnt update its "this" property properly

Tags: javascript, json, dom

So I'm making a website for a school project that displays reddit posts from certain sub reddit, and am currently trying to implement an infinite scroll feature where when you scroll to the bottom of the page, the site will generate more posts from that same sub reddit. The problem I am encountering is that when I try to call my loadData function again when the scroll bar reaches the bottom of the page, the JSON.parse(this.responseText) method gives me back a previously loaded this.responseText even though when I console.log(this) before and after the method call it logs the correct "this" value.

Sorry guys, this is my first question on stackoverflow so bear with me here. Here's some of my code.

```
let nextPage = '';
window.onscroll = function() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        let temp = nextPage;
        let prevPage = temp;
        const redditData  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        redditData.open('GET', 'https://www.reddit.com/.json?count=25&after=' + prevPage);
        redditData.send();
        redditData.addEventListener('load', loadData);
    }
};

function loadData(){
    const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    nextPage = jsonResponse.data.after;
    for (let i in jsonResponse.data.children){
        const pageContainer = makeElem('div', '.articles');
        const image = makeElem('img', '.image');
        if (!jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.preview){
            image.src = 'http://placekitten.com/400/200';
        } else if (jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.preview.images[0].variants.gif){
            let decodedImg = jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.preview.images[0].variants.gif.source.url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
            image.src = decodedImg;
        } else if (jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.preview){
            let decodedImg = jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.preview.images[0].source.url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
            image.src = decodedImg;
        }
        pageContainer.appendChild(image);
        let newH2 = makeElem('h2', '.header', jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.title);
        pageContainer.appendChild(newH2);
        let postInfo = makeElem('div', '.postInfo', 'by ' + jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.author + ' ' + moment.unix(jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.created).fromNow() + ' ' + jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.ups + ' views');
        pageContainer.appendChild(postInfo);
        let description = makeElem('div', '.descriptions', jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.selftext.substring(0, 200) + '...');
        pageContainer.appendChild(description);
        pageContainer.addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.location.href = 'https://www.reddit.com' + jsonResponse.data.children[i].data.permalink;
        })
        container.appendChild(pageContainer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We can't help you with code we can't see. Please update your question with a [mcve] showing the problem.

Comment: Seems like you're having a deal with closure.

Comment: can you specify where you put the `console.log` statements

Comment: I put them before and after the "const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);"

Comment: After further inspection of the jsonResponse variable I seem to be getting random subreddits when extending the page. Hmmmmmm

Comment: might be concurrency issue if calling the method outside of `.then`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to put a limit on my `redditData.open` method. Without it I wasn't getting the proper 'after' value from the JSON file. Thanks for taking the time to leave a comment. I promise I'll have a proper question with code samples next time.